# facebook iframe app: getSignedRequest and ['page']['admin'] returns fasle. Why?

Tags: facebook

I have an iframe (tab) facebook app which when someone visit it it (just) executes:

```
require_once 'src/facebook.php';
$config=array("appId"=>"xxxxxx","secret"=>"yyyyyy",'cookie' => true);   
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id=$facebook->getUser();

if($user_id)
{
    $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
    echo "SIGNED_REQUEST: ";
    var_dump($signed_request);  
}
else
{
  echo "Error. No user..."
}
```

and i see admin as false. In this test case it was me who were accessing my tab app. 
rem: I have a business manager for this app in order to get a user tocken for business (uniq id) and i have the role of administrator for me for for this app.
However when i access the app ['page']['admin'] returns false. Why does getSignedRequest do not recognize me as admin?

Comment: Are you admin of the _page_?

Comment: Sure! It was created by me

Comment: And you are logged in to Facebook using your own, personal _user_ account, and you are actually using Facebook _as_ that user account, and not “as a page”, or logged in via some other kind of account (since you mentioned the business manager and a token for business for some reason)?

Comment: Rem: my credentials for my personal account and for my Facebook for business/Buiness Manager are the same). If i logout from my personal account and business manager and login in personal account admin is false. If i logout personal account and login in business manager admin is true. It seems that page now belongs to the business manager and not to the personal account... This is a big thing for me in terms of problem solution... And now things are a bit clear... Well if am am developing app it make sense to login in business manager and forget the personal account for a moment. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

> .. i have the role of administrator for me for for this **app**

This field will return true if the user/viewer is an admin of the **page**. [See](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request):

> `true` if the loading user is an admin of the page, `false` if they're not.

Comment: Hence, the API has a bug because i am admin but it says false